# how to rank array's index in PHP

Tags: php, ranking

I need rank in my system. I have an array `$arr = array(120,26,38,96,22);`. I need to rank the index inside without changing their position.

The output I need is something like:

> 120 is rank 1, 26 is rank 4, 38 is rank 3, 96 is rank 2, 22 is rank 5

I've tried this, but all ranked as rank 1:

```
<?php
$arr = array(120,26,38,96,22);
$rank = 0;
$score=false;
$rows = 0;

foreach($arr as $sort){
    $rows++;
    if($score != $arr){
        $score = $arr;
        $rank = $rows;
    }echo $sort.' is rank '.$rank.'</br>';  
}
?>
```

And also I need the array length to be dynamic.

Comment: What kind of `rank` logic do you have?

Comment: I would do this by creating a 2nd copy of $arr array then sort it, then find the index # in the sorted array for every value in the unsorted array ..  Likely dozens of ways to do this see  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: If all positions are unique do: `sort($arr); $result = array_map(function($a){return $a+1;},array_flip($arr));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$arr  = array(120,26,38,96,22);
$rank = $arr;
rsort($rank);

foreach($arr as $sort) {
    echo $sort. ' is rank ' . (array_search($sort, $rank) + 1) . '</br>';
}
```

- Copy the original array as `$rank` and sort in reverse so the keys will be the rank -1
- Loop the original array and search for that value in `$rank` returning the key (rank)
- Add 1 since keys start at 0

Or another possibility:

```
$arr  = array(120,26,38,96,22);
$rank = $arr;
rsort($rank);
$rank = array_flip($rank);

foreach($arr as $sort) {
    echo $sort . ' is rank '. ($rank[$sort] + 1) . '</br>';
}
```

- Copy the original array as `$rank` and sort in reverse so the keys will be the rank -1
- Flip the `$rank` array to get values as keys and rank as values
- Loop the original array and use the value as the `$rank` key to get the rank
- Add 1 since keys start at 0

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$arr=array(120,26,38,96,22);
//get a copy adn use original for original order
$result=$arr;
//sort it numeric and reverse
rsort($result,SORT_NUMERIC);
//create the result
$result = array_map(function($a){return $a+1;},array_flip($result));
//print it
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [120] => 1 [96] => 2 [38] => 3 [26] => 4 [22] => 5 )
```

Get original order:

```
$resultxt = array();
foreach($arr as $sort){
  $resulttxt[] = $sort.' is rank '.$result[$sort];  
}
print implode(', ',$resulttxt).'<br>';
```

array_map http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

array_flip http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Comment: Except they want the original array values printed in the original order `120,26,38,96,22`.