# while loop inside foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

i want to make a table that on the first column consist of name from database and on the second column consist of value from an array.
this is what i have

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <?php $arr=array(3,5,2,4,1);                            
        $name= mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table")
        foreach ($arr as $rs){                          
            while($n=mysql_fetch_array($name)){ ?>                      
                <td><?=$n['name']?></td>
                <td><?=$rs?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   }   }   ?>                          
</table>
```

i need an output like

> name_a 3
>  name_b 5
>  name_c 2 
> name_d 4 
> name_e 1

thank you in advance.

Comment: as Rajdeep has shown, you dont need the foreach loop for this. In addition to that i wanted to tell you that you should try to use mysqli instead of mysql since mysql is deprecated. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that `foreach` loop. Simply use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) function inside `while()` loop to get each array element. So your code should be like this:

```
<table>
    <tr> 
    <?php 
        $arr=array(3,5,2,4,1);                            
        $name= mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table")                        
        while($n=mysql_fetch_array($name)){ 
            $rs = array_shift($arr); 
    ?>                      
            <td><?=$n['name']?></td>
            <td><?=$rs?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   
        }      
    ?>                          
</table>
```

Furthermore, your business logic work will work **only if** the number of the rows in the table equals to the number of elements in the array. And if it's not the case then you need to use `LIMIT` clause in your query.

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: thank you for the answer. but. don't you have another way? because the actual array comes from a sorting process. when i use the array_shift. the array element comes back to before it's sorted.. do you understand what i mean? i'm not good when it comes to array thing.. sorry for troubling you..

Comment: i dont think i completely understand, but have you tried sorting the array before the while loop?

Comment: @ゆにたどうえ As @Cashbee said above ^, you need to sort the array before using it in `while()` loop. Or can you at least show the code where you're doing sorting.

Comment: @Cashbee this was my question yesterday [rank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617333/how-to-rank-arrays-index-in-php) the $arr comes from there.. when i use array_shit() i got the original array back..

Comment: @ゆにたどうえ So this array `$arr` is rank array or element array? Please clearly explain your problem i.e. *what you're trying to do* and *what is not working*.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul the rank array.. i want to write the name who have the element in the 1st column and than the rank. in the 2nd column

Comment: @ゆにたどうえ Your question is not very clear. This answer aligns with the output format given in the question. May I know what output format you're expecting? Is it different from what you've shown in the question? Also, From where you're getting *elements* array? If the *name*s constitutes *elements* array, then how you're planning to rank them since they are not simple integers?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul no no. That's exactly how I want it to be. I need to make it in a table with 2 columns. The 1st column is the name from database and the 2nd one is from the rank array..

Comment: @ゆにたどうえ What's the current output now? And how is it different from the expected one? Post your *expected* and *current* output in [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thank you for keeping up with me. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7Hp1dSiz)

Comment: @ゆにたどうえ That's probably because you're using `array_shift()` function **outside** of the `while` loop. Isn't it?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul oh. I'm sorry. that was without array_shift().. with the array_shift() it becomes [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KBE4PqC0)

Comment: @ゆにたどうえ That's probably because you're applying `array_shift()` function on `$original` array, not on `$rank` array. The correct statement would be like this: `$rs = array_shift($rank);`. Also, make sure you use this inside `while` loop.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul omg.. it works now. i was out of focus. i'm so sorry for troubling you.. and thank you so much <3 <3 <3 <3 <3.